# Obtengo datos vacios al realizar una consulta con 5 tablas

Tags: mysql

Esta es la estructura de las tablas

Tabla grupo_usuarios y sus datos

```
CREATE TABLE `grupo_usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(150) NOT NULL
);

--Datos de la tabla grupo_usuarios


INSERT INTO `grupo_usuarios` (`id`, `nombre`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 'Enfermeros', 'Solo para los enfermeros del centro de salud'),
(2, 'Analistas', 'enfermeros analistas'),
(3, 'Comadronas', 'Comadronas del centro de salud'),
(4, 'Directivos', 'personal administrativo del centro de salud');;
```

Tabla Personal y sus datos

```
CREATE TABLE `personal` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
  `nombre_documento` varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
  `num_documento` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `telf` int(16) NOT NULL,
);

--Datos de la tabla personal

INSERT INTO `personal` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `nombre_documento`, `num_documento`, `telf`) VALUES

(1, 'Juan', 'Ciego', 'dip', 00091887, 222346575),
(2, 'Pedro', 'Mane', 'dip', 34560, 222345677),
(4, 'marta', 'sanchez', 'dip', 3785694, 2147483647),
(5, 'Cielo', 'Oyono', 'dip', 01191997, 551234554);
```

Tabla personal_grupo y sus datos

esta es la tabla que ha resultado de una relacion N:N entre personal y grupo_usuarios..

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_grupo` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `id_personal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY(id_grupo) REFERENCES grupo_usuarios(id),
FOREIGN KEY(id_personal) REFERENCES personal(id),
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

--datos de la tabla personal_grupo
INSERT INTO `personal_grupo` (`id`, `id_personal`, `id_grupo`) VALUES
(1, 2, 4),
(2, 2, 3),
(3, 4, 3),
(4, 5, 1);
```

Tabla permisos y sus datos

```
CREATE TABLE `permisos` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ;

--Datos de la tabla permisos

INSERT INTO `permisos` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES
(1, 'crear'),
(2, 'eliminar'),
(3, 'editar'),
(4, 'ver'),
(5, 'personal'),
(6, 'pacientes'),
(7, 'informes');
```

Tabla tiene_asignado y sus datos

Esta es la tabla que ha resultado de una relacion N:N entre  grupo_usuarios y permisos

```
CREATE TABLE `tiene_asignado` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_permisos` int(11) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY(id_grupo) REFERENCES grupo_usuarios(id),
FOREIGN KEY(id_permisos) REFERENCES permisos(id),
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


--Datos de tiene_asignado



INSERT INTO `tiene_asignado` (`id`, `id_grupo`, `id_permisos`) VALUES
(1, 3, 5),
(2, 2, 7),
(3, 4, 6),
(4, 4, 3),
(5, 5, 1),
(6, 1, 1);
```

Necesito obtener el nombre del personal llamado Pedro, el nombre del/los grupos a los que pertenece y los permisos que tienen asignados sus grupos

Al ejecutar mi consulta me devuleve valores vacios

..Mi consulta

```
SELECT u.id, u.nombre, pg.id_personal, pg.id_grupo, g.id, g.nombre, 

pm.id, pm.nombre, ta.id, ta.id_grupo, ta.id_permisos FROM personal u


INNER JOIN personal_grupo pg ON u.id = pg.id_personal

INNER JOIN grupo_usuarios g ON pg.id_grupo = g.id

INNER JOIN tiene_asignado ta ON pg.id = ta.id_grupo

INNER JOIN permisos pm ON pm.id = ta.id_permisos



WHERE  u.nombre = 'pedro';
```

Comment: ¿Tus tablas tienen datos? Una forma de depurar es ir poniendo los `JOIN` uno a uno, cuando pongas el `JOIN` tal y ya no muestre datos, sabrás que hay un problema en esa tabla.

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo de los datos que pudieran tener las tablas? De esta forma podríamos asesorarte mejor sobre la solución del problema.

Comment: @5n10m ya he editado la pregunta con un ejemplo de la informacion que tengo almacenada en la base de datos

Comment: Por defecto, 'pedro' no es igual a 'Pedro'.

Comment: @Alfabro, gracias x la observacion, ha sido un error mio, pero aun corrigiendolo, al volver a ejecutar la consulta, no se soluciona el problema

Comment: @Alfabravo, es cierto, pero no del todo, ya que depende de la colación. Si la colación es `*_ci` (case insensitive) es igual.

Comment: @Marcos por eso dije _por defecto_. :P

Comment: @Alfabravo, si, y lo tuve presente al responder, porque en realidad depende de la configuración de `MySQL`. En mis instalaciones (_viejas_) es `utf8_general_ci`. Mira [este ejemplo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bs9ehFsgmG28jR4H4ASUgH/0)

Answer (score 2):

Tenés un error en el `JOIN` con la tabla `tiene_asignado`, esto:

```
INNER JOIN tiene_asignado ta ON pg.id = ta.id_grupo
```

Debería ser así:

```
INNER JOIN tiene_asignado ta ON g.id = ta.id_grupo
```

El campo `pg.id` es la clave primaria de la tabla `personal_grupo`, no el `ID` del grupo.

Comment: buena observacion, ya lo he corregido!!

Comment: @user287003 ya que estamos, te aconsejo realizar el [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por la ayuda, ya lo consegui haciendo un LEFT JOIN y corrigiendo lo
que me ha indicado Marcos

```
SELECT u.id, u.nombre, pg.id_personal, pg.id_grupo, g.id, g.nombre, 

pm.id, pm.nombre, ta.id, ta.id_grupo, ta.id_permisos FROM personal u


LEFT JOIN personal_grupo pg ON u.id = pg.id_personal

LEFT JOIN grupo_usuarios g ON pg.id_grupo = g.id

LEFT JOIN tiene_asignado ta ON g.id = ta.id_grupo

LEFT JOIN permisos pm ON pm.id = ta.id_permisos


WHERE  u.nombre = 'pedro';
```

Comment: El INNER JOIN tambien me funciona